# Just HOW do I get this pesky error away in unity2d?

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, text, sprite

hello so im codiing in unity C# and i keep getting this error for my inventory slot script and I have no idea on how to get it away! if you could help thank you!

heres the error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of 
the collection.
Parameter name: index
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, 
System.ExceptionResource resource) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at 
<fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
InventorySlotHandeler.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/InventorySlotHandeler.cs:24)
```

and heres the script that the error is targeting

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventorySlotHandeler : MonoBehaviour
{
public SpriteRenderer SlotSprite;
public string SlotName;
public int slotnumber;
public GameObject player;
public TextMeshProUGUI SlotNameText;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   
}

// Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
  {
    SlotSprite.sprite = player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().Inventory[slotnumber].ItemSprite;

    SlotName = player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().Inventory[slotnumber].ItemName;

    SlotNameText.text = SlotName;

    
  }
}
```

Comment: It tells you that slotnumber you set is negative or bigger than the amount of inventory slots. It must be between 0 and slots count minus 1.

Comment: in my player script you start our with a peice of paper so thats already 1 item there (also im beginner coder so i dont understand lists much and this was my first using them)

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform some error checks in your script:

```
void Update()
{
    if(slotNumber < 0)
        return;
    var inventory = player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().Inventory;
    // I'm assuming inventory.Count gives you the number of item in your collection.
    // If it's an array you have to use inventory.Length here.
    if(inventory == null || slotNumber >= inventory.Count)
        return;

    SlotSprite.sprite = player.GetComponent<PlayerScript().Inventory[slotnumber].ItemSprite;

    SlotName = player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().Inventory[slotnumber].ItemName;

    SlotNameText.text = SlotName;
}
```

Although the interesting question is where your invalid index comes from. You should perform some validation before setting it and when your inventory size changes.

Also you should not call `GetComponent<T>()` every frame. Just add a member variable for your inventory and store it in `void Awake()` method.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you are not assigning any number in your Int slotnumber. You are running this in Update so it’s run immediately and thus you are getting an array bounds error.